# AngularJS ng-repeat do not refresh after model change with $rootScope error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, rootscope

Hello members of AngularJS, I am a newbie towards Angular facing this problems where my ng-repeat does not refresh the page after a model change even I had already manually reload the model after post. All functions that I created works flawlessly as I can store data / delete on the database side just that it will not perform on page refresh unless I manually click on F5. This is my approach on the js side.

```
'use strict';
var eXcomments = angular.module('eXcomments', ['ngAnimate']);
eXcomments.controller('eXcommentsCtrl', function($scope, $http){

$scope.comments;
$scope.inputcomment;

$scope.getComments = function(topic_id){
    $http.get('index.php?r=exploreComment/WS_getExploreComments&topic_id=' + topic_id, {cache:false}).success(function(data){
        $scope.comments = data;
        console.log($scope.comments);
        console.log('Comment Loaded');
    });
};


$scope.init = function(topic_id){
    $scope.getComments(topic_id);
};

$scope.post = function(topic_id){
    $scope.getComments(topic_id);
    console.log('Reload Comment Success');
};


$scope.makePost = function(topic_id, user_id){

    var formatJSON = {
            user_id: user_id,
            topic_id: topic_id,
            data: escape($scope.inputcomment),
    };
    var json = JSON.stringify(formatJSON);
    $http.post('index.php?r=exploreComment/WS_PostComment&json=' + json);   
    console.log(json);
    console.log('posted');
    $scope.inputcomment = "";

    $scope.getComments(topic_id); 
    console.log('Reload Comment Success');
};

$scope.removePost = function(topic_id, comment_id){

    $http.post('index.php?r=exploreComment/WS_deleteComment&cid=' + comment_id);
    $scope.getComments(topic_id);
    console.log('Delete');
    console.log('Reload Comment Success');
    $scope.$apply('comments="null"');
};

});
```

I have created individual modules for different page handling and then inject it on a root app like this.

```
var myapps = angular.module('myapps',['customDirectives','imgGall','starApp', 'NavBarModel', 'Carousel', 'eXcomments','confirmButton','Status']);
```

and this is how my HTML layout looks like.

```
<html>
<!-- Layouts for Comment Display -->
</html>
<div ng-controller="eXcommentsCtrl"
ng-init="init(<?php echo $topic_id?>)" ng-model="comments">
<div class="exploreNoCommentBlock" ng-if="comments.length == 0">
    <h4 style="text-align: center">No Comments Yet... How about leaving
        yours above?</h4>
</div>

<div class="exploreCommentBlock" ng-repeat="comment in comments">
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr style="width: 100%">

            <td style="width: 5%" rowspan="2" valign="top"><img
                src="<?php echo UrlMgmt::getUserResourceUrl()?>{{comment.user_id}}/avatar/{{comment.avatar}}"
                , style='height: 64px; width: 64px; border-radius: 5px;' /></td>



            <td style="width: 70%"><span class="author_name">{{comment.username}}</span>

AND----SO----ON
```

From time to time when perform a delete action, it will keep showing me this error thus freezing the entire operation but changes does occur on the database side.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.h [as fn] (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:140:152)
at k.$digest (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:109:352)
at k.$apply (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:112:345)
at HTMLDivElement.j (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/ui-bootstrap-0.11.0.min.js:8:1779)
at HTMLDivElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://localhost/viralenz/assets/4483d5da/jquery.js:3058:9)
at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle.eventHandle (http://localhost/viralenz/assets/4483d5da/jquery.js:2676:46) 


Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply
at Error (native)
at http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:6:450
at m (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:105:34)
at k.$apply (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:112:276)
at k.$scope.removePost (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/ng.js:395:10)
at http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:176:387
at N.(anonymous function) (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:53:175)
at k.$eval (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:112:15)
at k.$apply (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/angular-1.2.22/angular.min.js:112:293)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost/viralenz/themes/viralenz/js/ng.js:103:27)
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I would guess this has to do with your php code in the html page. Angular is for client sided single page applications which do not reload and therefore do not run the php parts. Is this php page a template/partial/view or your main page?